# How to set the length in java regex pattern?

Tags: java, regex

How would I set a length within a Java regex pattern?

```
package basic;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex2 
{
    public static void main(String...aq)
    {
        String a = "1234";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{3-8}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(a);
        if(m.find())
            System.out.println(m.start());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: At least add some text explaining the issue you're facing. What you're trying to solve, and what is your question. If you can't put efforts in writing a well-worded question, how can you expect someone else to put efforts helping you?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#greedy

Answer (score 2):

I believe if you change the {3-8} to {3,8} it should get you strings between 3 and 8 characters.

Comment: how to set the length of atleast 3?

Comment: @user3235308 You use {3,}

Comment: how i can check the input in the format (90,60) with in the range as first number (-90-+90)and second number(-180-+180)

Comment: @user3235308, regex is for character parsing - it can't do numeric range validation.